# Django - Get 404 because our installation does a strange url rewrite

Tags: django

Django - server shared by several developers  Each developer has an assigned number - mine is 30, so the access url for my testing host is example.com/dev30.  This gets redirected (nginx) to example.com:5030/dev30 (note the port based on my assigned number).

For Django, I was able to get the site to display by naming the app 'dev30', but I don't think this is a good solution and certainly not in the spirit of Django.

What can I do with my urls.py files for a better solution?

My current /urls.py file is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dev30/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^dev30/', include('dev30.urls')),
)
```

My /urls.py file is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^log/', views.log, name='log'),
)
```

The documentation I found addressed dynamic hosts and other situations but I didn't find any about a host pattern like the one above.

Comment: Then rename dev30.urls to your app name

Comment: The thing is, the url by which the app is accessed will always be example.com/dev30 - this is immutable.

Comment: I was talking about the include part.

Comment: karthikr - please upgrade your comment to an answer so I can mark you up.  This solved my problem and the whole team's problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Sure, Added an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dev30/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^dev30/', include('dev30.urls')),
)
```

to

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dev30/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^dev30/', include('dev.urls')),
)
```

Now, though multiple developers are working on the project, the app name would not change.

As a part of the configuration, the individual developer (31) can change to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dev31/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^dev31/', include('dev.urls')),
)
```

and so on...

and your nginx config would be the way you are doing all this while.